# Flow enum is not defined

Tags: webpack, babeljs, flowtype

I'm trying to use flow enums. Here is what I have done so far:

I installed `babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums` as a dev dependency.
I installed `flow-enums-runtime` as a regular dependency.

I loaded the babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums plugins using `.babelrc`:

```json
{
    "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums"]
}
```

I added an dummy enum in a js file:

```js
// @flow
// imports...

enum Foobar {
    Foo,
    Bar,
}

// The rest of the app...
```

Running the `flow` command from `flow-bin` seems to handle the enum appropriately.

However, `npm run build` outputs the following error:

```
ERROR in src/App.js
  Line 4:6:  'Foobar' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 5:5:  'Foo' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 6:5:  'Bar' is not defined     no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 1 error in 52 ms
```

I'm struggling to figure out what's wrong in my setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you eventually resolved your issue? (Because I have the same one...)

Comment: Yes, there was no solution at the time, but using hermes-eslint is the way to go now.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the meantime, I managed to make it work without using hermes-eslint. The code parsing is OK but I'm  now facing another issue since Babel won't transform my enums. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102296/flow-enum-is-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment129773552_71102296

Comment: I just enabled flow enums just as explained [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/enums/enabling-enums). When I add en enum in my project (something like the sample in question), the app crashes with error:  `Syntax Error: Unexpected reserved word 'enum'.`. Anyone knows what's going wrong?